# Using Array statements in SQL together with Where clause outputs extra rows with null values but it shouldnt

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, where-clause

I started experimenting with BigQuery and I encountered SQL syntaxes such as *array* and *unnest*. I created a nested table (is this the correct name? ) and wrote an example query(below)
[image]

I wanted to get the department of 'enes' so I wrote this query:

```
  SELECT
     dept,
     ARRAY(SELECT  employeeName FROM UNNEST(name) AS employeeName
     WHERE (  (employeeName LIKE 'enes') and 
              (employeeName is not null))) AS EmpNameDisplay 
  FROM EmployeeTable
```

**however results looks like this :**

[image]

**Why it brings the second row? What if I had million departments and it will try to bring them all?**

I reformed the table in a way it doesnt include nesting tables. And when I use where statement to choose the department of 'enes' it only showed only one result which is correct. Why this nesting causes such abnormaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
with EmployeeTable as
  (
              select 'Data Engineer' as dept, ['enes','emre','john'] as name
    union all select 'Manager' as dept, ['machiavelli','john'] as name
  )
select  t1.dept,
        employeeName
from    EmployeeTable t1,
        UNNEST(t1.name) as employeeName
where   employeeName = 'enes'
;
```

If you don't need employee name in the result list (department name only), you can use this:

```
with EmployeeTable as
  (
              select 'Data Engineer' as dept, ['enes','emre','john'] as name
    union all select 'Manager' as dept, ['machiavelli','john'] as name
  )
select  t1.dept
from    EmployeeTable t1
where   'enes' in UNNEST(t1.name)
;
```

Comment: Enes Kuz, in your query you filter not departaments, you filter names in arrays for every department, making these arrays smaller or empty.

Comment: can you share an short example scenario when to use these 2 ways?

Comment: I am gonna read your answer after some break. My mind is tired. But from the looks of it you also answered my another question.

Comment: The first query provides data for a request "Give me a list of departments, where works the given employee (or employee**s**) and display data in format DEPARTMENT+EMPLOYEE". The second query provides data for a request "Give me a list of departments where works the given employee. And display only departments name."

Comment: Thank you a lot Max. This answer works perfectly. Do you have any recommendations as a source to learn about this kind of SQL ?

Comment: When I asked for examples of 2 scenarios i was referring to your first comment. Think about my original query in the question. What it achieves by filtering the names in arrays for every department? Can you think of any use case?

Comment: Regarding recommendations. For me, this official docs work in 90% cases (if we're talking about arrays and unnesting): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#filtering_arrays.

Comment: Regarding use cases of filtering data in arrays. I can't find a good example for Departments and Employees. But in my work I come across Googe Analytics data in BigQuery, which has huge arrays of different parameters. Often happens that I don't need all these parameters, but only a few items. In these cases I get rid of most these items and leave one or two. In such cases the array filternig can be helpful.